# CSS alignment difficulty

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.one {
    width: 13%;
}

.two {
    width: 30%;
}

.three {
    width: 30%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class= "one">Quantity</th>
        <th class= "two">Info</th>
        <th class= "three">Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity1" value=""/>
        <td class = "two">Cheap Monday Jeans 30/34 </td>
        <td class = "three">$39.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity2" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">Herschel Bag (free) </td>
        <td class = "three">$129.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity3" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">Diesel t-shirt (s) </td>
        <td class = "three">$59.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity4" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">Superdry Patrol Lite Jacket (m) </td>
        <td class = "three">$129.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity5" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">I love Canada t-shirt (s) </td>
        <td class = "three">$19.99 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the table rows (clothes information & prices) to be aligned right below the table headers. Meaning, I want it to be centered. I don't know why table rows are skewed to the left and cannot be aligned right below to the headers.

Even tried 
td { text-align: center; }, but doesn't work.

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17983973/edit) your former question instead of reposting it. Also show us there how you've tried `text-align` and why that didn't work.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/u7WzM/

Answer (score 1):

Left align the `th` header elements. You could also center align the `td` elements but it doesn't look as pretty.

```
th.one {
     text-align:left;   
}
th.two {
     text-align:left;   
}
th.three {
     text-align:left;   
}
.one {
    width: 13%;
}

.two {
    width: 30%;
}

.three {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: He wanted them centered.

Answer (score 1):

Hey see this demo hope it works for you 
[link](http://codepen.io/anurag-ans/pen/arepk) 
These are the only changes you have to do in your **CSS** part :

```
.one {
    width: 1%;
    text-align:center;
     }

.two {
     width: 10%;
     text-align:center;
     }

.three {
    width: 10%;
    text-align:center;
       }
```

**The output that i got was like this** :

---

[image: The output of above code.]

---

I hope this is what you want .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want something left aligned to line up beneath something center aligned.  Your best bet is probably to left align the headings and using some padding to provide space between the columns.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th class= "one">Quantity</th>
    <th class= "two">Info</th>
    <th class= "three">Prices</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity1" value=""/></td>
    <td class = "two">Cheap Monday Jeans 30/34 </td>
    <td class = "three">$39.99 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity2" value=""/></td>
    <td class = "two">Herschel Bag (free) </td>
    <td class = "three">$129.99 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity3" value=""/></td>
    <td class = "two">Diesel t-shirt (s) </td>
    <td class = "three">$59.99 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity4" value=""/></td>
    <td class = "two">Superdry Patrol Lite Jacket (m) </td>
    <td class = "three">$129.99 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity5" value=""/></td>
    <td class = "two">I love Canada t-shirt (s) </td>
    <td class = "three">$19.99 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
.one {
    width: 13%;
}

.two {
    width: 30%;
}

.three {
    width: 30%;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
.two, .three {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpmmk/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should make the `<th>` elements align left:

```
th {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Also, you should consider using the `<colgroup>` tag, with nested `<col>` tags to style your table columns, as such:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="one" />
        <col class="two" />
        <col class="three" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Info</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity1" value=""/>
        <td>Cheap Monday Jeans 30/34 </td>
        <td>$39.99 </td>
    </tr>
    ...rest of the code
```

This way, you don't have to add the "class" attribute to ALLLLL the `<td>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/u7WzM/2/

Right align, and center.

```
th.one, td.one {
     text-align:center;   
}
th.two {
     text-align:center;   
}
td.two {
     text-align:right;  
    padding-right:5%;
}
th.three, td.three {
     text-align:center;   
}
.one {
    width: 13%;
}

.two {
    width: 30%;
}

.three {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center;` to the css classes.

```
.one {
    width: 13%;
    text-align:center;
}

.two {
    width: 30%;
    text-align:center;
}

.three {
    width: 30%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Or add

```
td
{
   text-align:center;
}
```